# How to bake Boolean as a normal map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, baking

I have a revolver barrel, one of them is a low poly, and the other is a high poly. The high poly has lots of holes inside it, and the low poly doesn't have any. I don't want to ruin my topology/UV's so i would like to "bake" the Boolean's of the high poly object to the low poly. Is it possible? I really don't want to UV unwrap and Boolean again. I have tried doing the booleans and UV-unwrapping but 1. it increases the polycount and 2. when i join the two objects and reset and UV-unwrap again, it is a mess.

[image]

I tried baking it from high poly to low poly like a normal map, but i do not get good results, regardless if i bake in Substance Painter or Blender:

[image]

I do not understand why it is not working, So does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: You could just copy the whole ordeal, apply it and just bake it with a cage on the the low poly model.

Comment: @Sidar So bake it like your baking from a high poly to a low poly? I already tried that and it does not give the desired effect, unless you mean something else.

Comment: It should work fine. What happens if you try? Can you edit your question with a shot of the normal map and what the low poly looks like with it applied?

Comment: Just added it, as you can see it turned out horrible :(

Comment: Tried what exactly? there are a few ways of doing a bake for normal maps. Make sure the rays are long enough. show us the normal map

Comment: Once again... don't use Booleans folks, [model with proper topology](http://topologyguides.com/post/133528602155/a-simple-method-of-modeling-a-classic-shape) instead

Comment: Normal maps are just lighting information it is not geometry so it can only do bumps and small details not holes or Geometry.